# Role based access in yii2

Tags: yii2

How can I make role based access in yii ?
 I need to provide features for the users based on the role.  I need to give role based access to different users. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use yiisoft/yii2/rbac  module 
very easy to use and configure and complete

see 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html
for a brief guide